# foobar2000 music library is empty

Tags: foobar2000

My music is stored in `C:\Users\user\Music\`. Apparently "library viewer selection playlist" must be enabled in order to your audio files being automatically loaded.

[image]

both tabs are blank:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do it:

1. To see all your files inside 'Library Viewer Selection', go to menu:

Library > Album List

2. Search for something:

Ctrl+S

3. From your PC's file/folder explorer, you can drag and drop files and folders into foobar.

Note:

Since you are new to foobar please check a lot of youtube videos. foobar is a highly 'non intuitive' old player with a huge learning curve. But once you learn it, it becomes a powerful player. This is the only player that I use to date. But for new users like you, a player like musicbee might be better.